# Multiline string replace with pretty indentation

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace, indentation

I want to do multi-line string replacements in some template files, but retain a pretty indentation.

Here's an example of the template:

```
<TAG1>
    <TAG2>
        %REPLACETHIS%
    </TAG2>
</TAG1>
```

Now, when I simply replace the string %REPLACETHIS% with a string like

```
<REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
    replacedstringtext
</REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
```

it will look something like:

```
    <TAG1>
        <TAG2>
            <REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
    replacedstringtext
</REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
        </TAG2>
    </TAG1>
```

when it should look like:

```
    <TAG1>
        <TAG2>
            <REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
                replacedstringtext
            </REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
        </TAG2>
    </TAG1>
```

It gets even more complicated because the template will be part of a bigger template where it should be indented correctly as well.

I'm trying to achieve this in Perl, but basically the problem is the same in all the languages I know.

Has anyone a better idea than to just replace line-by-line with variables that keep track of the current indent depth? Which is very cumbersome due to the multi-level-template structure.

Basically, what I need is a substitute for a simple regex that will not only put the first line of the substitution string at the right column, but puts every line on that column. So if %REPLACETHIS% is at column 10, all the lines in the replacement string should be put at col 10... maybe there is some tricky built-in magic with regexes in Perl?

Comment: Have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~pip/XML-Tidy-1.12.B55J2qn/Tidy.pm

Comment: @M42: I ended up doing it with Tidy. Works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Now that your template files are in XML format, you could use some XML processing modules to handle it. It's more flexible and reliable.

For your case, [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXML-2.0116/LibXML.pod) could handle perfectly:

```
use XML::LibXML;
use XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint;

my $xml = "template.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $tree = $parser->parse_file($xml);
my $root = $tree->getDocumentElement;

my ($replace_node) = $root->findnodes('/TAG1/TAG2');
$replace_node->removeChildNodes();
my $new_node = $tree->createElement('REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1');
$new_node->appendText('replacedstringtext');
$replace_node->addChild($new_node);

my $pp = XML::LibXML::PrettyPrint->new(indent_string => "\t");
$pp->pretty_print($tree);
print $tree->toString;
```

Comment: Hmmm. That could work. Also a bit cumbersome though, because unlike in the example, I have lots of those templates.... but still, I'll think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not convinced regex is the correct approach for this, however if you use a group to capture the indentation before `%REPLACETHIS%`, you can just enter it back into the subsitution.

e.g.

```
s/(.*)%REPLACTHIS%/$1<REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>\n$1    replacedstringtext\n$1</REPLACEDSTRINGTAG1>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/uL0yK8/1)

Comment: That's a good idea. Not sure it is doable this way in my actual application. Because unlike in the example, I don't have the replacement string handy at the same time I do the replacement in the template. First I build the replacement string, then I replace the template with it. So I need to do like a "s/^(.*)/$1$2/" before I can do the s/// you suggest, but then I don't have the correct $1 yet...